# Customer dimension in data warehouse - mix persons with companies

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse

We do have a mix of customers - most of them are persons, but some of them are companies. These two groups both share the same set of facts, however their dimensional attributes are different (sample):

```
Person
 FirstName
 LastName
 BirthDate
 Sex
 Region
 City
Company
 Name
 RegistrationNumber
 Region
 City
```

Is it good idea to include both persons and companies in one dimension?

```
Customers
 FirstName
 LastName
 BirthDate
 Sex
 Name
 RegistrationNumber
 Type (Person,Company)
```

It is good to mention that there are also self-employed customers - in such case they have all attributes of person and company.

If I use two dimensions, it will make all the analytical stuff harder, because most of the time I'm interested in both groups. On the other hand, there will be a lot of default values if I use one dimension only. I've checked "The Data Warehouse Toolkit", but found no relevant information.

Questions I have - should I create two tables, one table or use a completely different approach to design customer dimension in data warehouse?

Comment: a case of subtypes/supertypes, see, e.g., here: http://basicofcomputer.com/supertypes_and_subtypes_entities.htm

Comment: @koriander That is actually the way how it's done in our production system. Do you use this design in data warehouse?

Comment: I suppose it will depend on the your specific data warehouse, but it is common to have hierarchical dimensions and different levels of the dimension can have different attributes. I'm afraid I don't have much experience to share with you and I can only advise to check the features of your OLAP system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it good idea to include both persons and companies in one dimension?

In a data warehouse, yes.  The information is not going to be updated, you're not concerned about the empty or default columns, and ease (speed) of querying is more important.

One reason you normalize data in an operational database is to remove the possibility of update anomalies.  When the data is stored in more than one place, it can be updated in one place and not the other.

Comment: Agreed. So long as "persons" and "companies" truly are both "customers" with the same measures, and there isn't a need for analysis by "buyer" within a company.

Answer (score 0):

My reason is for the scenario you explained, we can maintain two dimensions and can include two keys in Fact.

Fact may contain PERSON_KEY and CUSTOMER_KEY. So, if it's a person PERSON_KEY can be -1 or if it's other way COMPANY_KEY can be -1. This can be considered if person or company details needs to be used for some other purposes within the system. I think dimension means going to possible granular level.

Comment: What is the advantage of this design?  It involves two `INT`s in the fact table instead of one, so there's a cost that needs to be outweighed.